# cygwin unable to open gnome-session

Tags: x11, gnome, windows, cygwin

On windows 7, I installed Cygwin, xorg-server, gnome-desktop, gnome-session.

I start X `startxwin` and the X server starts.  I can run `gedit` and a gui of the gnome editor will start.

If i run `gnome-session` then, it gives this output:

```
$ gnome-session
gnome-session-binary: PID 8140: WARNING: Using null backend for session tracking
Unable to init server: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

Any ideas how to start gnome?

Comment: are you setting DISPLAY in some way ?

Answer (score 1):

https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2015-10/msg00111.html

> '-nolisten tcp' is now the default, so the server only accepts local
>   connections on a unix domain socket. A '-listen' option has been added
>   which can be used to restore the previous behaviour.

For connection to 127.0.0.1 you need to set `-nolisten tcp`, however currently the programs should not need it. May be something is requiring 127.0.0.1 for gnome-session like a old setting ?

```
$ echo $DISPLAY 
:0.0
```